# How to make the inner white space created by border-radius transparent?

Tags: css, firefox

If you check out [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/57nj4t6d/2/), you may notice the white space created by the `border-radius` property.

I tried to get rid of it by doing:

`background: transparent`

but it made it blue instead.

How do I fix this? I need to get it working in Firefox only.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/57nj4t6d/2/)

Comment: Is this just a problem in 1 specific browser? It's looking fine for me in IE11.

Comment: @wf4 Just Firefox. Question updated.

Comment: That also happens in Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the background for pseudo elements and add them thick border of the same color, then increase the border radius to make the inner curve visible:

```
.tail:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid #4196C2;
}

/* ... */

.tail--left:after {
  left: 0;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* ... */

.tail--right:after { 
  right: 0;
  border-width: 10px 0 0 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}
```

**See [JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/57nj4t6d/4/).**

You can even do it without extra spans: http://jsfiddle.net/57nj4t6d/5/